# ffmpeg says: "option framerate not found"

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

Good afternoon.

I've been trying to use ffmpeg to split a .mpeg into a sequence of .jpeg images. Please note that this is the inverse problem of the one specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735823/ffmpeg-not-finding-codec-parameters), but the problem I'm facing is not the same as the problem the author of that thread is facing.

Specifically, I have tried all the following mpeg codecs available in my ffmpeg installation:

```
DEV D  ffv1            FFmpeg video codec #1
DEVSD  ffvhuff         Huffyuv FFmpeg variant
DEVSDT mpeg1video      MPEG-1 video
D V DT mpeg1video_vdpau MPEG-1 video (VDPAU acceleration)
D V D  mpeg2_crystalhd MPEG-2 Video (CrystalHD acceleration)
DEVSDT mpeg2video      MPEG-2 video
DEVSDT mpeg4           MPEG-4 part 2
D V D  mpeg4_crystalhd MPEG-4 Part 2 (CrystalHD acceleration)
D V DT mpeg4_vdpau     MPEG-4 part 2 (VDPAU)
D VSDT mpegvideo       MPEG-1 video
D V DT mpegvideo_vdpau MPEG-1/2 video (VDPAU acceleration)
D VSDT mpegvideo_xvmc  MPEG-1/2 video XvMC (X-Video Motion Compensation)
DEVSD  msmpeg4         MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 3
D V D  msmpeg4_crystalhd MPEG-4 Part 2 Microsoft variant version 3 (CrystalHD acceleration)
D VSD  msmpeg4v1       MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 1
DEVSD  msmpeg4v2       MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 2
```

I've tried supplying ffmpeg with all different codecs to try to split an input .mpeg video file with 2548 frames into 2548 .jpegs, by using the -vcodec option:

```
ffmpeg -r 2548 -i frames.mpeg frames_%06d.jpg -vcodec $codec
```

where `$codec` is any codec among the ones listed above, e.g. `ffv1`, `mpeg4`, etc. However, all my efforts result in the following error:

```
[NULL @ 0x1948f20] Value 4707126720094797824.000000 for parameter 'probesize' out of range
[NULL @ 0x1948f20] Value 4707126720094797824.000000 for parameter 'analyzeduration' out of range
[NULL @ 0x1948f20] Value 4697254411347427328.000000 for parameter 'indexmem' out of range
[NULL @ 0x1948f20] Value 4703785510416416768.000000 for parameter 'rtbufsize' out of range
[NULL @ 0x1948f20] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'fpsprobesize' out of range
[NULL @ 0x1948f20] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'f_err_detect' out of     range
[NULL @ 0x1948f20] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'err_detect' out of range
Option framerate not found.
```

Which is weird, because I've actually specified the frame rate parameter through the -r switch. I googled a bit and it appears that this error was mentioned approximately a year and a half ago [on the ffmpeg bug tracker](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/926) but that information makes little sense to me because it's relevant to the devs. Curiously, if I interchange the position of the parameters and put -r after -i or even after -vcodec, the error message changes to:

```
[NULL @ 0x24abf20] Value 4707126720094797824.000000 for parameter 'probesize' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24abf20] Value 4707126720094797824.000000 for parameter 'analyzeduration' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24abf20] Value 4697254411347427328.000000 for parameter 'indexmem' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24abf20] Value 4703785510416416768.000000 for parameter 'rtbufsize' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24abf20] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'fpsprobesize' out of  range
[NULL @ 0x24abf20] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'f_err_detect' out of  range
[NULL @ 0x24abf20] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'err_detect' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4686111960511545344.000000 for parameter 'b' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4683532506232782848.000000 for parameter 'ab' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4705844345939427328.000000 for parameter 'bt' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4617315517961601024.000000 for parameter 'me_method' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4622945017495814144.000000 for parameter 'g' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4611686018427387904.000000 for parameter 'qmin' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4629418941960159232.000000 for parameter 'qmax' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4613937818241073152.000000 for parameter 'qdiff' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'wpredp' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'bug' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'er' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'err_detect' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4613937818241073152.000000 for parameter 'ec' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4620693217682128896.000000 for parameter 'ildctcmp' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4620693217682128896.000000 for parameter 'subq' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4696837138094751744.000000 for parameter 'ibias' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4696837138094751744.000000 for parameter 'pbias' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4642507528377204736.000000 for parameter 'lmin' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4660262442142531584.000000 for parameter 'lmax' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4696130710463840256.000000 for parameter 'flags2' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'threads' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4620693217682128896.000000 for parameter 'nssew' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4586705114244317184.000000 for parameter 'profile' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4586705114244317184.000000 for parameter 'level' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4623507967449235456.000000 for parameter 'skipcmp' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4642507528377204736.000000 for parameter 'mblmin' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4660262442142531584.000000 for parameter 'mblmax' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4643211215818981376.000000 for parameter 'mepc' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'bidir_refine' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'cqp' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4627730092099895296.000000 for parameter 'keyint_min' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'refs' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'directpred' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4618441417868443648.000000 for parameter 'sc_factor' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4643211215818981376.000000 for parameter 'mv0_threshold' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4630826316843712512.000000 for parameter 'b_sensitivity' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'compression_level' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'min_prediction_order' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'max_prediction_order' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'prediction_order_method' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'min_partition_order' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'max_partition_order' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4607182418800017408.000000 for parameter 'ticks_per_frame' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4611686018427387904.000000 for parameter 'color_primaries' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4611686018427387904.000000 for parameter 'color_trc' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4611686018427387904.000000 for parameter 'colorspace' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'aq_mode' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'rc_lookahead' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'lpc_type' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'lpc_passes' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value 4613937818241073152.000000 for parameter 'thread_type' out of range
[NULL @ 0x24b23c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'request_sample_fmt' out of range
frames.mpeg: could not find codec parameters
```

I'm at a loss as to what to do with this problem, and am looking for some assistance.

Kind regards,

Jason

Comment: This was solved (refer to my answer underneath).

Answer (score 4):

I found out what was wrong with this, and it had to do with my debian installation. I would advise all debian users to install the deb-multimedia repository to their systems, by following the instructions on the relevant [website](http://deb-multimedia.org/). This did the trick for me, because both ffmpeg and a bunch of other libraries were updated automatically after I added that repository and did an aptitude update/safe-upgrade.

Marking this solved.

Jason

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling with a similar error while trying to record video from a webcam with avconv; I followed your advice and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to convert a video as an image sequence, you only have to use a cmd line like

```
 ffmpeg -i frames.mpeg frames_%06d.jpg
```

the -r option make sense only if you want to dump a subset of frame per seconds (below 10 fos)

```
 ffmpeg -i frames.mpeg -r 10  frames_%06d.jpg
```

But if the problem is still here, it looks like decoder report error in the video elementary stream itself. To check that point, use ffplay to see if it decode or not....

Comment: Unfortunately, without using the -r flag, I consistently get the second kind of error. Interestingly, I receive the exact same error by typing `ffplay frames.mpeg`, as you suggested. Any clues?

Comment: First, check that you have a "recent" ffmpeg build and after try playing or analyzing that stream with another tool. I don't know form where it comes from but its compliance with the standard is suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

For me this meant I was configuring ffmpeg like "./configure --disable-everything" and then not adding a single demuxer in.  Go figure.
So this got past it: `--disable-everything --enable-demuxer=image2`

Comment: funny, i was using apt-get